# wso2 data mapper SequenceMediator Runtime error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to use the data mapper to map the response from two(2) different api. So what I did was use the clone mediator and aggregate mediator to merge these two api together and then map it using the data mapper but when I get on the data mapper part I always get an error. It works if I removed the data mapper mediator part.

Here's my api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/test" name="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="ROOT" scope="default">
                <root:movie xmlns:root="www.wso2esb.com"/>
            </property>
            <log level="full"/>
            <clone continueParent="true" id="movie" sequential="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint>
                                <address format="rest" uri="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt0918940?api_key=code"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </send>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint>
                                <address format="rest" uri="https://www.omdbapi.com/?type=movie&amp;i=tt0918940"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </send>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <aggregate id="movie">
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="ROOT" expression="//jsonObject/*" xmlns:dummy="http://org.dummy" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/TestMapping.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/TestMapping_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/TestMapping_outputSchema.json" outputType="JSON"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <respond/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>

        </outSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

and here's my log

```
[2016-07-21 09:33:56,180] ERROR - SequenceMediator Runtime error occurred while mediating the message
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputReader.readFromInputStream(JSONInputReader.java:76)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputReader.read(JSONInputReader.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.InputBuilder.buildInputModel(InputBuilder.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.core.mapper.MappingHandler.doMap(MappingHandler.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:306)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMapperMediator.java:256)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:57)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.completeAggregate(AggregateMediator.java:447)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.mediate(AggregateMediator.java:330)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:57)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:325)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:338)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:125)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:56)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:300)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:255)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your governance registry whether you add configuration correctly into ESB. (Navigate to Governance registry)

[image]

You will get null pointer exception as it can't find relevant details. Please add relevant configurations and test.

Comment: Add property before data mapper mediator. Then it looks like: <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/><log level="full"/> <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/TestMapping.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/TestMapping_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/TestMapping_outputSchema.json" outputType="JSON"/>

Comment: If you still get the error add logged data as we put log mediator between property and datamapper mediator

Comment: the Sequence Runtime error is now gone but I am stuck. It looks like the response from one of the api that I called http://pastebin.com/SveYFnk2 and here's  my new api http://pastebin.com/tky5PBcm

Comment: What is the issue now you have?

Comment: It doesn't return the mapped response from data mapper. All I see from my terminal log is the merged response  in xml instead of json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117870/discussion-between-kevin-and-dilshani-subasinghe).